# EF7 RC2 Code First Create Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF7 RC2 in my ASP.NET core RC2 application and I'm trying to generate my db from code (I'm using code first).  I created my context, and setup my connection string, but when I enter "Add-Migration" in the NuGet console in VS2015, I get an error saying

> The term 'Add-Migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

I did some digging, and I think that command is an RC1 thing.  Is there an RC2 equivalent?  Are there any tutorials out there for EF7 RC2?  All I could find are for RC1 or early.

Comment: i would recommend that you add the extension "Open Command Line" to your visual studio. it allows you to right click the project and open a cmd on it. and from there you do the dotnet commands

Comment: I wrote a small getting started tutorial for using Entity Framework with ASP.NET Core RC2. http://totaltechware.blogspot.com/2016/05/aspnet-core-rc2-web-app-with-postgresql.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a regular command prompt with the new `dotnet` tooling installed from RC2, you should be able to do the following within your project's directory:

```
dotnet ef migrations add [name]
```

As a quick note, you may want to explore the new commands to see what's all in each item. Such as `dotnet` vs. `dotnet ef`(https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/16/announcing-net-core-rc2/)

You may need to ensure Powershell 5 is installed to get this to work within the Package Manager Console:

https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/rc1-rc2-upgrade.html#package-manager-commands-require-powershell-5

You also need to add this to your project.json file and `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" :  "1.0.0-preview1-final"` to your dependencies.

```
"tools": {
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
    "imports": [
      "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
      "portable-net45+win8"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use RC2 with Windows 7. It just means that you will need to use a normal command prompt / VS cmd prompt instead of the `Package Manager Console`. There is also a note saying that this is a temporary dependency:

This is a temporary requirement that will be removed in the next release (see issue [#5327](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5327).

Answer (score 0):

This is for Entity core but you can try. These are the two commands you need:

```
dotnet ef migrations add somename
dotnet ef database update
```

Answer (score 0):

For Entity Core...go to package Manager within visual studio and then simply type: update-database

this should create the tables in the persistent store specified